# How can I manipulate and change the default checked button in a v-radio-group mandatory

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

I'm trying to change the default checked button in my form according to the database data
I can acess this data with

```js
item.france
or
france
```

So I want to change the default checked button according to the data stored in my database, the problem is that when I apply the attribute "mandatory" to my v-radio-group I can't change the default checked button even If I try to add :checked="true"

```js
<v-radio-group v-model="item.france" row mandatory>
 <template v-slot:label>
  <div>France</div>
 </template>
  <v-radio label="Oui" :checked="false"></v-radio>
  <v-radio label="Non" :checked="true"></v-radio>
</v-radio-group>
```

Is there a way to change the default checked, and also a way to change it's value according to my data.

Any help is greatly appriciated, thanks !

Comment: You should add a `:value` binding to your radio buttons - each button should have a distinct value. This is how Vuetify detects which radio button to select depending on the `v-model`. Without values it does not know which button to check.

Comment: Ok thanks i'll try, but when you have added a different value for each one how can you tell the v-model to select a specific one ?

Comment: Simply by assigning the corresponding value literal to the `v-model` variable. If you want to select `Non` then you assign `true` to `item.france`, otherwise `false`. If you assign `undefined` to `item.france` - none of the radio buttons will be selected.